# Independent and Identically distributed random variables with value at risk

Tags: risk

Suppose that $W_1$ and $W_2$ are i.i.d. and $P(W_i>x)=x^{-1/2}$ and $x$ is greater than or equal to $1$ and $i=1,2.$ How do you show that $P(W_1+W_2>x)=(2\sqrt{x-1})/x$? I know it involves calculus either differentiation or integration but I am not sure how to go about it. Any ideas?

Also, how do I use this above information for W to show that the value at risk (VAR alpha) is super-additive for all alpha values within 0 and 1 meaning that How do I show that VAR alpha(W1+W2)>VAR alpha(W1)+VAR alpha(W2). Any ideas?

Comment: Add the self study tag.

Comment: It seems you haven't started by [searching](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) (say on *sum of random variables*); there are numerous posts that discuss the procedure with independent variates (generally by [convolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution_of_probability_distributions) -- [e.g. see this pdf](https://www.dartmouth.edu/~chance/teaching_aids/books_articles/probability_book/Chapter7.pdf)). For example, see the following posts on our site ...

Comment: 1. https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/331973/why-is-the-sum-of-two-random-variables-a-convolution  2. https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/106410/pdf-of-a-sum-using-convolution 3. https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/115198/sum-of-random-variables

Comment: If after reading the links (the last link in my first comment has numerous examples) you have a specific question, please post a new question.

Comment: Also note that you can use the fact that $F_{W_{i}}(w_i)=1-P(W_i\le w_i)$ and from here, pdfs can be worked out as well as joint pdfs given independence.